# How specific to make my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a specific situation:

- 10th level witch
- standard starting wealth (62K GP) plus and the ability to choose Scribe Scroll if it turns out to be worth it
- a ratling familiar (with the ability to cast any spell of any class/level from a scroll, no UMD needed)
- joining a party where the only other casters are a blaster-sorcerer, a master summoner, and some paladins with wands of CLW (no full divine casters).
- Heading into the Worldwound on a crusade (not based on any published AP)

And I want advice on what scrolls to invest in (for myself and/or my familiar).

I can mention all of these details in the question...but since Stack Exchange sites aim to help others in similar situations **I'm wondering if there are some useful generalizations I could make to the question, to make it (and the answers it attracts) more useful for other readers.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make your question as specific as you can.

While we do like things to be useful to others, the most important thing is that it *helps you.* So make your question as specific as you feel it needs to be to get a usable answer.

Generally when people try to generalize we'll ask them to be more specific. Be specific. It helps to give all the relevant details and let the answerer sort out what is important.

Comment: Also, "what scrolls should I have" is too general without more in the way of goals.

Comment: @JeffFry Also bear in mind that there's little-to-no harm in having a question put on hold if it comes to that. Ask the question you want answered; if there's an issue of scope, it'll be put on hold and we'll work with you to fix those issues. So it might be put on hold as too localized if it really were super-specific, but if it were, no harm done: we'll just fix it.